# What is this specific method called?

Tags: methods

I'm curios as to what this specific method is called:

```
public Word(String word) {
    this._word = word;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a **constructor**. In this case, it would be for a `Word` object. It takes parameters to assign values to instance variables (in this case, the `String word`.)

[Here is a link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to the Oracle documentation on providing constructors in Java for further reference.